# Error adding vagrant box in PHPStorm 7, ruby.exe error

Tags: ruby, vagrant, phpstorm, vagrantfile

My PHPStorm 7 installation is throwing this error whenever I try to add a box. Am I missing something?

[image]

I pointed to the vagrant.bat in installation directory as told [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/02/vagrant-improvements-in-latest-phpstorm-update/)

Am I supposed to install ruby too? Didn't say something like that in vagrant's site though.

Comment: Wrong path to vagrant.bat? http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Vagrant+Support+in+PhpStorm

Comment: @LazyOne There's only one 'vagrant.bat' file, and it is in that location. The bin folder has a 'vagrant' file and a 'vagrant.exe' file.

Comment: Can you point to exe file instead? Just the path you are using right now suggests that it is ruby related...

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks! That works. :) I don't understand though, even in the PHPStorm documentation they seem to point to the .bat file?

Comment: Well .. I'm not using vagrant myself (I've installed it .. but did not actually had a chance to actually try it) ... but that article/manual was done for older version (where .bat file seems to be the one to use). My only thought was (and still is) -- that .bat you have used seems to be the wrong one (purely based on the path).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path to the `.bat` file you are using (`...\embedded\gems\...`) suggests that it is ruby related .. and *may* require ruby for proper executing (the error message you see confirms such suggestion).

Instead, choose vagrant executable from `C:\Program Files (x86)\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin\` folder.

If `.bat` file is absent -- choose `.exe` one instead.